Android studio coverage test missing (grey out)
A Coverage test button is grey out, and a coverage run selection is missing
I did not update any extension, and it always worked but suddenly it is gone/missing
What I've to try

Invalidate cache & restart
Repair IDE

but still does not work yet
coverage select always here but gone

button grey out

Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Patch 1
